# How would I create a multidimensional table from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several hundred **items** each with a **group number** and a **rank**. I would like to put a nice looking table which arranges  into a grid of **ranks** across the top and **groups** up and down. Each intersection (ie a given group and rank) could have no items or several items. So size of each cell/intersection would have a variable length.

See image attached - dataframe at top and desired output in bottom.

[image]

Comment: Use this one: ```df = pd.DataFrame({"Items":["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"], "Group":["A", "A", "A" ,"C"], "Rank":[1,1,2,3]})
df.pivot_table(index="Group", columns="Rank", aggfunc=list)```

Comment: @ashish14 - thanks.  That works.  The only issue is that within box the items are listed as [item1,item2, etc...] instead of vertically without the square brackets. Any way to change that?